# Is there a way to optimize my NOT IN query to speed it up a little?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that I am using to exclude specific field values from one of my tables. My table is very large ~27 million records, my current query takes approx. 10-15 mins to complete, so any speed up would be greatly appreciated.

I have an index on C1, C2, C3, and C4, that is trying to scan the entire table.

Removing the NOT IN and just chaining "AND C3 <> 'Exclude 1'" uses an index on C1, C2, and C4 and I am not entirely sure why.

Should I just drop the NOT IN or is there something I am missing?

Query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT C1)
FROM
  TABLE
WHERE
  C2 >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 120 DAY
  AND C3 NOT IN (
    'Exclude #1',
    'Exclude #2'
  )
  AND C4 = '0';
```

Comment: The order of the columns in the index is `C1, C2, C3, C4`?

Comment: No, they are ordered how they appear in my columns. C3, C2, C4, C1.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a left  join  and check for null value

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C1)
FROM  TABLE
LEFT JOIN (
  select 'Exclude #1' C3
  union 
  select 'Exclude #2'
) t ON t.C3 = TABLE.C3
WHERE t.c3 IS NULL
AND TABLE.C4 = '0';
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I am actually having a tricky time getting this query to run.

It gives me an error with this line:
    t t.C3 = TABLE.C3

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't t.C3 = TABLE.C3 WHERE TABLE.c3 IS' at line 7

Comment: Query returns 0 for my table.

Comment: Query is certainly faster, clocked it at 8 mins, but the count is incorrect, unfortunately.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample you expected  result and you actual resul